# Could anyone help me explain why we need componentDidMount on presentational component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

For example, for the example below why we need to use fetchPosts to fetch all posts under componentDidMount on the post index component?

```
class PostIndex extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchPosts();
    }

    render(){
       const {posts, deletePost} = this.props;

       return (<div>
           <ul>
               {
                   posts.map(post =>
                       (<PostIndexItem 
                           post = {post}
                           deletePost = {deletePost}
                           key = {post.id}
                       />) 
                    )
               }
           </ul>
           <CreatePostFormContainer/>
       </div>)
    }
}

export default PostIndex
```

Comment: because setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` is one of several [react lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) methods used to control when state can be updated and component renders can be triggered. In this case, `componentDidMount` is called (only) once when the component has been built, inserted into the DOM and is ready to be rendered, i.e. it is ready to be viewed. It is synonymous to an `onLoad` type event. It is recommended to fetch data or issue other various "side-effects" here as that is when the component is guaranteed to be mounted and state and props accessible. Side-effects may update state, thus causing a re-render because state has changed.

Conversely, if you fetched your data in the render function and updated state, that would cause a re-render which would again call to fetch data, trigger a re-render, and again... well, hopefully you see how this pattern ends (or doesn't).

`componentDidMount` isn't really specific to "presentational" components, as technically I would say all react components are "presentational", as in, they usually are rendering something to the DOM.

[edit to address question]

For "refreshing" there are multiple possible solutions. A really simple solution is to use a "refresh" button where the `onClick` handler fetches your data, updates state (and triggers a re-render). Another solution is to instead setup an interval in `componentDidMount` to periodically refetch data, but remember to clear the interval in the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle function. Yet more advanced methods rely on external state management (redux/thunks/epics/sagas) to manage data fetching and connecting to the UI.

The quick advice is "No side-effects in the render cycle", use the react lifecycle functions (or hooks for functional components) to issue side-effects and/or update state.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But my another question is: if we put fetchPosts under componentDidMount, and later there is new post saved to the backend database. since componentDidMount is called only once, how it ensures the posts it fetched include all posts (especially those added later to the database)?

Comment: @Sunny Tried addressing your question.